# Modify zoom center in Leaflet library? setZoomAround works but not interactive

Tags: leaflet, zooming

I could use setZoomAround, but how can I cancel the default action in onZoom event?

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the leaflet code, you will see, that you can't disable the zoom-events. But you can try to set a Flag.

```
zoomaround = false;
function example(){
   zoomaround = true;
   map.setZoomAround(latlng,zoom,options);
   zoomaround = false; //You have to test if this works, because I think the event calling is async and then this line will not work.
}

map.on('zoomstart',function(e){
   if(!zoomaround){
       //default code
   }
});

map.on('zoomend',function(e){
   if(!zoomaround){
       //default code
   }
   zoomaround = false; //Use this line if the line above not working.
});
```